# Ruby on rails: Creating a home page with elements pulled form different models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im having difficulty moving forward with my app. The problems I face are:

App: Beat selling website.

I am looking to have a home page with a : Jquery photo slider, Social bar for (twitter,Facebook,youtube), a video box, an opt-in box, and a benefits box outlining 6 benefits of the company.

I want to have all the above elements on one page (home) but have an admin interface where I can Add new photos to the photo-slider by uploading, update the video box via youtube url, manage the form for opt in and have a list of all users that have opt-in and also for the benefits i would like to be able to administer the benefits, add new one and delete old one.

So the problem I face is: I understand I have to create a controller model and view for each module I want placed on the home page. Do I need to create a MVC called HOME too? I also plan to use partials so I can pull it all together then on the main HOME page. How do I display all the modules above on the one page for the user to see, Do I need to set up some sort relationship between each controller?

I should also mention I'm using user authentication so I will have the admin pages protected.

rails version 2.3.5,
ruby version 1.8.7,

Please if you can help out it would be much appreciated,

Thanks, Ian

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be slightly confused with what views do. You don't need to create a view for each model unless you want to view them separately (i.e. only that model).

What you want to do in your case is to have a controller (such as `HomeController`) with an `index` action where you gather all the data you'll to show (models, etc). Then, in `app/views/home/index` you use your partials to show your data with something like

```
<%= render 'pictures/show_inline', :picture => @picture %>
```

Of course, you'll need a partial in `app/views/pictures/_show_inline.html.erb` that will display a picture like you want it (using the `picture` variable we call the partial with).

Comment: Thank you v.much I will look into this now. Im new to ruby on rails and really appreciate you commenting back to my problem.

Comment: If you're serious about learning rails, two books I can recommend are http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails and http://www.manning.com/katz/ . There is also a free online tutorial http://ruby.railstutorial.org/

Comment: Im very serious about learning. I have checked out the agile book i will look at the katz one and i have ruby.railstutorials.org bookmarked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Both of those books are very good. The agile book is probably easier for beginners, while the "Rails in Action" book goes into more detail and would be better suited to a "experienced programmer, new to Rails" type of person. Good luck !